# Displaying results on new line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an ajax request below that successfully returns the results. The results return is like the below.

**Results structure**

[image]

This is the ajax request that returns the structure above.
**File**

```
$.ajax({
          url: domain+$(this).val(),
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function (results) {
             $("#suggesstion-box").show();
             $("#suggesstion-box").html(results);

             console.log(results);
          },
            
 });
```

Now how do I make the results return in the `#suggestion-box` like like this way?

```
Internet Explorer 

Internet Speed Test

Internet
```

At the moment, it shows like this in my `#suggestion` box with the code above

```
Internet Explorer, Internet Speed Test,Internet
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first split the *result* using comma, then join them using `<br/>` (if element is a div element) or `\n` (if element is an input element):

```
$("#suggesstion-box").html(results[1].split(',').join('<br/>'));
```

Demo:

```js
var results = 'Internet Explorer, Internet Speed Test,Internet';
$("#suggesstion-box").html(results.split(',').join('<br/>'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="suggesstion-box"></div>
```

Comment: its says results.split is not a function

Comment: @RoboPHP, you should take the value from second index `results[1].split(',').....` , also how the element `#suggesstion-box` looks like is it a div or input?

Comment: Thanks. I had to include toString() to results to make it work.  `results[1].toString().split(',').join('<br/>')`

Answer (score 0):

**Not the shortest option nor the best**, but another option is to use the array map function.

I created a separated function to handle:

1. Create new html element (p)
2. Append the item to the new element.

Inside my map method, for each item inside the array, I called my function and appended the returned result (an html element) to my div.

```
const myDiv = $( "#suggesstion-box" );

const createMyElement = (el) => {
  const newElement = document.createElement('p');
  newElement.innerHTML = `<p>${el}</p>`;
  return newElement;
};

$.ajax({
  url: domain+$(this).val(),
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function (results) {
    $("#suggesstion-box").show();
    results[1].map(el => myDiv.appendChild(createMyElement(el)));

  },
```